# Is there any way to filter table visual in one page by selecting any data point from another page scatter chart in power bi?

Tags: powerbi, dax, scatter-plot

I need to show the filtered data only in table visual in target page based on point selection in scatter chart in source page.

Tried out some work around on my own but cannot do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `drill through` from `scatter chart` to `Table visual`